# Changed Entity Framework v6 to Entity Framework v4.4 - getting error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have created an ASP.NET MVC application and my Entity Framework version is 6.0.0, but I want Entity Framework version 4.4.0.

I have referenced version $.4.0 dll and also changed the version in `package.config`.

I am getting this error:

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1705  Assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' with identity
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 
>   'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly 'EntityFramework' with identity  'EntityFramework,
>   Version=4.4.0.0,  Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'  Final   c:\users\navya\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\Final\Final\Models\IdentityModels.cs

Please let me know where I have to make changes when I change my Entity Framework versions in my reference.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to go backwards in EF versions?  I highly doubt Asp.Net Identity will run on an old EF version.  EF 4 is over 5 years old.

Comment: Try to change the targeting framework. (not entity framework but the .net framework from 4.6 to 3.5/4) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: Do not change versions in the package.config file. Use NuGet package manager. You can change the version there or at least uninstall EF6. You may have to change the target framework in order to be able to install EF4. That may clear the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put - you can't do that. Identity library was compiled against EF6 and it won't work with lesser version. [Upgrade path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469466(v=vs.113).aspx) from 4 to 6 lists breaking changes that will not let you use v4 in any scenario.

You can get the [source code](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/), change EF version there, adjust source code to work with v4, build binaries, reference the binaries in your project directly without NuGet package => profit (or rather a step back and a maintenance nightmare)

Or you can build your own implementation of `IUserStore` that relies on EF4 and make Identity use your implementation.

Other than that you are out of luck. You shouldn't really use EF4, but I suspect this is not your decision to make.